# is there is a node, among geometry nodes, that outputs an object ( orange slot )?

Tags: procedural, geometry-nodes

I would like to make a grid of lines: how to transform lines into objects that I can plug into "Point instance" ?

I have inspected all the nodes, there is no node, in the current release of Blender, that outputs an object. How to complete this step ?

[image]

Comment: @Chris ok, I'll do things differently

Comment: A work around could be to add a single vertex and inside that you could make your grid using geometry nodes. An use that inside the original geometry nodes  Point Instance as an object, but depending on your main goal, that could be Useless

Answer (score 2):

In my (17/09/2021) verion of Blender 3.0, you can instance internally generated geometry by using the highlighted dropdown. If you convert the curve a to mesh *after* instancing, you can give the instances a bevel..

[image]

Comment: ...and where can he now connect this to an orange slot...?

Comment: You could create a gnode object and instance that result again and again. E.g. you create a leave. This would be your instance object for your tree. And this your instance object for your forest. And this your instance object of the world. All in one tree.

Comment: Yes, but In one nodetree? Where the „partial“ result of the nodetree is the instance of the next part?

Comment: e.g. i would love to make a grid by myself with spheres. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVrxo.png. it would be great if i could plug in now from geometry to point instance object so that my meshline -x is my point instance object. So the red line is what i would love to do. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5h4B.png. AFAIK this is only possible with a seconde geometry nodes object: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRiD9.png

Comment: I can do this...https://imgur.com/rstvyac ? Is that it?

Comment: Whaaaaat!? is that the "field"-version? why didn't you show that node in your answer? ;)

Comment: but in my point instance node there is no dropdown!? i just have object and collection....

Comment: aaaah...ok, it is in the newest blender update...mine was a few days old....

Comment: @Chris I downloaded this a couple of days ago.. `blender-3.0.0-alpha+master.e6fa74ffed5f-linux.x86_64-release`

Comment: Ok! Thanks! Now GN made a big step further!!